# ASP.NET MVC 5: EmailAddress attribute custom error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

In register form I use EmailAddress attribute to validate user email.

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pole wymagane")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any chance to show what is wrong with email address if validation fails? For example 'oops, I see that your email address contains whitespace'

Comment: `[EmailAddress]` is regex validation attribute and it either passes or fails. You would need to write you own validation attribute if you wanted to test for specific failures.

Comment: Did you add ValidationFor label inside your html?

Comment: You gotta write custom validation attribute for that...

Comment: You can't use `EmailAddressAttribute` to create custom validation class derived from it, but you can extend from `ValidationAttribute` when creating specific validation rules to email address field instead using default one.

Comment: I thought that I would have to write custom validation, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have to add another validation for that. Example using `[RegularExpression]`

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pole wymagane")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\S*$", ErrorMessage = "Email Address cannot have white spaces")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own regular expression for email:

```
// built-in [EmailAddress] does not allow white spaces around email
public const string EmailValidationRegEx = @"^\s*\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*$";
```

*Note: I have just added white spaces around the existing [.NET regex pattern for email match](http://emailregex.com/):
`"^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$"`*

Now you can use this new regex pattern instead of `[EmailAddress]` attribute:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    private string _email;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pole wymagane")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [RegularExpressionWithOptions(EmailValidationRegEx, ErrorMessage = "Invalid email")]
    public string Email 
    { 
        get => _email;

        set
        {
            _email = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? string.Empty : value.Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have modified the setter to `trim()` the `value`. This ensures that we always get rid of extra white spaces before using the email value.