# ASP.NET MVC 5 EmailAddress attribute not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I use `EmailAddress` attribute. When you type `tom@jerry` it accepts as a valid email. When I type `tom@jerry.` only then it complains. How can I solve this problem so the validation complains when given input like `tom@jerry`.

Comment: We have nothing to do with `EmailAddress` attribute. If you want more than 99% correct, try to use regex instead

Comment: Unfortunately the `EmailAddressAttribute` and `jquery.validate.js` use slightly different regexs for validating email addresses (you can inspect the source code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs) and [here](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation). You can always write you own validation attribute that extends `RegularExpressionAttribute`

Comment: That's because it is syntaxically valid (according to RFC) email.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement regular expression on top of it
like this one is for white spaces

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\S*$", ErrorMessage = "Email Address cannot have white spaces")]
```

Here is the link for similar problem

[ASP.NET MVC 5: EmailAddress attribute custom error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890299/asp-net-mvc-5-emailaddress-attribute-custom-error-message)